# How to display all doc_types under a particular index in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an index I want to display all the `doc_types` under this particular index`(index1` here). I have tried this code:

```
es.get(index='index1',doc_type='*',id='*')
```

But Its showing error. Any idea how to display this ?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: TransportError(404, '{"_index":"index1","_type":"*","_id":"*","found":false}')

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
body ={"size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "doc_type_aggregations": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
      }
    }
  }
}

es.get(index='index1',body=body)
```